# Variable is both nil as well as not nil within rspec test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec-rails

This is the strangest bug I've seen in my years of programming. Please ignore the strange idioms I am using below as I am using trailblazer, a programming framework for Rails:

The code below

```
let (:app) { App::Create.(app: {name: "Half-Life", steam_id: "70"}).model }

it 'gets app details from Steam' do
  VCR.use_cassette('app/get') do
    p app.id
    app_id = app.id
    app = App::Get.(id: app_id).model
  end

  expect(app.app_type).to eq('game')
end
```

works as expected.

The code below

```
let (:app) { App::Create.(app: {name: "Half-Life", steam_id: "70"}).model }

it 'gets app details from Steam' do
  VCR.use_cassette('app/get') do
    p app.id
    app = App::Get.(id: app.id).model
  end

  expect(app.app_type).to eq('game')
end
```

throws an undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass in the line

```
app = App::Get.(id: app.id).model
```

However the line

```
p app.id
```

which is just before the offending line displays the correct id.

What could possibly be going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
let (:app) { App::Create.(app: {name: "Half-Life", steam_id: "70"}).model }
```

creates a method called `app` that returns an `App` when invoked. (It memoizes the result, so it will always return the same `App` after the initial invocation.)

This line:

```
app = App::Get.(id: app.id).model
```

creates a **new local variable** called `app` that is ambiguous with the method `app`. According to [the Ruby docs on assignment](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Local+Variables+and+Methods):

> In Ruby local variable names and method names are nearly identical. If
>   you have not assigned to one of these ambiguous names ruby will assume
>   you wish to call a method. Once you have assigned to the name ruby
>   will assume you wish to reference a local variable.
>
> The local variable is created when the parser encounters the
>   assignment, not when the assignment occurs:

So at the moment when you try to assign to `app`, a new local variable is created. When the right-hand side of the assignment is evaluated, `app.id` tries to call `id` on the local variable `app` (which so far is `nil`).

Here's the simplest code I can think of that reproduces the issue:

```
def a
  "Hello"
end

p a.upcase # "HELLO"
a = a.upcase # undefined method `upcase' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

There are a couple ways to fix your code. I think the best solution by far is:

```
app2 = App::Get.(id: app.id).model
```

The name `app` was already used by a method... don't hide it by creating a local variable with the same name.

You could also do this:

```
app = App::Get.(id: app().id).model # the parens disambiguate
```

or the solution you already have:

```
app_id = app.id # capture the ID before the local variable gets created
app = App::Get.(id: app_id).model
```

But I think both of those are worse than simply not creating the naming collision in the first place.

Comment: Thanks, this makes a lot of sense.